# How to pass int parameter to OpenQuery sql

Tags: sql-server

I have this query, however it gives me an exception of converting the varchar to int. Is it possible to use an int instead of declaring it as a varchar(max)?

```
DECLARE @Filtro int, @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Filtro = 1;
SET @SQL ='SELECT *
FROM OpenQuery(MACPAC, ''SELECT FET001.ET0109,  count(FET001.ET0101)
FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.FET001 FET001
WHERE (FET001.ET0104=''''POE'''') AND (FET001.ET0105=''''DIS'''')
GROUP BY FET001.ET0109
HAVING COUNT (FET001.ET0101) > ''''' + @Filtro + ''''''')';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: `CONCAT` takes care of conversions implicitly and is quite convenient in cases like this.

Comment: @JeroenMostert only true if he's working with SQL Server 2012 or later

Comment: Yes i'm working on SSMS 2016

Comment: You can convert the INT variable @Filtro into character format using convert(varchar(10),@Filtro) in dynamic SQL generation SET statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just Cast the INT value to Varchar before appending

```
DECLARE @Filtro int, @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Filtro = 1;
SET @SQL ='SELECT *
FROM OpenQuery(MACPAC, ''SELECT FET001.ET0109,  count(FET001.ET0101)
FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.FET001 FET001
WHERE (FET001.ET0104=''''POE'''') AND (FET001.ET0105=''''DIS'''')
GROUP BY FET001.ET0109
HAVING COUNT (FET001.ET0101) > ''''' + RTRIM(LTRIM(CAST(@Filtro AS VARCHAR(20)))) + ''''''')';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are concatenating a string literal with an `INT`, thus the error. Convert the `INT` to a `NVARCHAR` first. You can keep your variable as an `INT`.

```
DECLARE @Filtro int, @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Filtro = 1;
SET @SQL ='SELECT *
FROM OpenQuery(MACPAC, ''SELECT FET001.ET0109,  count(FET001.ET0101)
FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.FET001 FET001
WHERE (FET001.ET0104=''''POE'''') AND (FET001.ET0105=''''DIS'''')
GROUP BY FET001.ET0109
HAVING COUNT (FET001.ET0101) > ''''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @Filtro) + ''''''')';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Didn't think it was that simple! Lots of answers though. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you want to use your `@Filtro` variable in your dynamic query, you should cast it to `nvarchar` just like this: `CAST(@Filtro as nvarchar(N))`